# How to call an Ajax function inside infinite while loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

could anyone tell me how to run Ajax function inside infinite while loop?

```
while(true){
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: {'constraintId': experimentId},
         url: '/calender-generation-status/',
         success: function(data){
              console.log("inside ajax");
     }
  });
}
```

The problem with this code is the while loop keeps running before success attr and all the statement after success attr has not been executed.

Comment: Use `fetch`, promises, and `await` would help

Comment: Use websockets instead of long polling (especially in a while loop with hundreds of requests per second). You are DDoSing your own server

Comment: @JonasLochmann - `setInterval` with XHR tends for a chaotic process, best avoided.

Answer (score 6):

Websockets would probably be a better approach to what you're doing, though of course it's impossible to say without knowing more. Constantly making XHR calls to the server is a lot of work for both ends.

But re your question: To implement your loop, you don't use a loop at all; instead, you start the next call from the `complete` callback:

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: {'constraintId': experimentId},
         url: '/calender-generation-status/',
         success: function(data){
              console.log("inside ajax");
         },
         complete: doAjax   // <===
    });
}
```

or better:

```
function doAjax() {
    var stop = false;
    doCall();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            stop = true;
        }
    };
    function doCall() {
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: {'constraintId': experimentId},
             url: '/calender-generation-status/',
             success: function(data){
                  console.log("inside ajax");
             },
             complete: function() {
                 if (!stop) {
                     doCall();
                 }
             }
        });
    }
}
```

...which returns an object to the caller of `doAjax` with a `stop` method that can be used to stop the process.